# I am missing the gitconfig file in my home directory, in fact it doesn't exist anywhere

Tags: git

There is no gitconfig file in any directory, I'm sure of that. I'm wondering what the best course of action is form here as its very inconvenient not having the file. I've tried reinstalling git but that effects very little.

Comment: Does `git config --global -l` show anything?

Comment: What is inconvenient?  If ~/.gitconfig or $GIT_DIR/config  (or /etc/gitconfig or $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config) do not exist, create one of them by assigning a value in the appropriate scope.  If something is inconvenient, presumably this is because some value that you expect to be configured is not.  Configure it, and the file will be created for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply:

- check where it could be with (using Git 2.26 or more):

  ```
    git config --show-origin --show-scope --global -l
  ```
- create one with, for instance:

  ```
    git config --global user.name <me>
    git config --global user.email <me@email.com>
  ```